# Locked out of my Twitter account—need temporary password

Tags: twitter

I am locked out of my Twitter account because when I access from my phone it says, “create temporary password on twitter.com” and when I try to login to Twitter on web it says, “sent verification request to app.”

How do I fix this problem? I tried everything. I already reset my password.

Answer (score 1):

From the Twitter [Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/15365#) :

> I am receiving the password reset emails but I still cannot log in!
>
> Try again – the links in those emails are time-sensitive. Be sure you have not copied and pasted any extra spaces if you copy the link into your browser's URL bar.
>       Try logging in from a different browser (we suggest Firefox, which can be downloaded for free) or another computer.
>       Make sure your browser accepts cookies. Before saving your new password, you should also try clearing your browser's cache.
>       Still not working? [File a support ticket here](https://support.twitter.com/forms/signin).

So it looks like you already reset your password but still can't login, I suggest you [contact them](https://support.twitter.com/forms/signin).